# Does 'can' express Obligation, Permission or Ability here?

Tags: questions, modal-verbs

The sentence is:

"Rajen, can you please take her home?"

What does 'can' indicate here? Obligation, Permission or Ability?

I think it must be Ability, but my teacher says it must be Permission, so what do you think it really indicates? Explain.

Comment: It's a ***request***, which you can think of as a "watered-down" version of ***obligation*** if you like. Or an "upscaled" version of ***ability*** (asking if you have not only the *ability*, but also the *will* to perform the requested action).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was part of a paper, what exactly must be the answer if the options are Ability, Obligation or Permission?

Comment: @Anay Karnik: Well, I don't have to sit the paper, so I can afford myself the luxury of saying it's rubbish. I expect the person who set the test is expecting "ability", but I can't for the life of me see how tests like that are supposed to quantify a person's linguistic competence. Nor do I see that it's worth trying to *teach* English by making such distinctions - they were only ever relevant in the context of learning ***Latin***, where the categorisation affects the morphology of some words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh yeah, I agree with you. I also don't like how they ask such questions many a times, which really doesn't test or teach anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.  "D. None of the above" would be the correct answer

Comment: Naming the question a polite request is on target. Literally, _Can_ does ask about ability, so that answer is not wrong. In reality, it implies _If you have the ability, please proceed to act on it, to_ take her home." If I ask if you would like to dance and you say yes, should I go find you a partner -- or was I not already inviting you to dance _with me_?

Comment: @Kevin: I *assume* OP is a non-native speaker (just from general context, not from any obviously non-idiomatic usages here! :) But it's at least *possible* the teacher is also nns, and/or isn't a reliable guide when it comes to identifying what the examiner expects as the "correct" answer. As I said previously, I don't think this particular categorisation system is really relevant to English in the first place, but that's not exactly a helpful perspective for someone who needs to pass an exam, no matter how meaningless the question/answer might be.

Comment: ...whatever - I stand by my previous assertion that the question might do better on ELL, so I've closevoted accordingly.

Comment: Naming the question a polite request is on target. May I = Permission, Can = Ability, so that answer is not wrong. In reality, it implies "_If you have the ability, please proceed to act on it, to_ take her home." If I ask if you would like to dance and you say yes, should I go find you a partner -- or was I not already inviting you to dance _with me_?

Comment: @FumbleFingers This "categorization" is just [functional-notional approach](https://www.ukessays.com/essays/english-language/a-notional-functional-syllabus-essay.php) to ESL, and has been in use for like 40 years. However, in the hands of a pedantic nns with little feel for usage, it may be harmful or limiting in practice.

Comment: Somebody with Aspergers syndrome would most likely take the literal meaning of the sentence and hear "do you have the ability to take her home?". The actual social meaning of the question is "Please will you take her home?".

Comment: When :can: is used like this, it really doesn't mean Obligation, Permission or Ability.  The closest replacement word is "would".  You can also look at it as "are you in a position to".  Ability is assumed.  It's more a combination of willingness and circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

In informal English, by saying "Rajen, can you please take her home?" the speaker is essentially asking "Rajen, if you are able to take her home, please do so." It's kind of a mix between ability and obligation in terms of how pressured one feels to perform the action.

However, this isn't formally correct. Nobody would call you out on this fact though, except perhaps an English language teacher in the classroom.